# apache listening to 7080 after installing ubuntu desktop (gui) on 10.04 vps

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, vnc

Before ubuntu desktop was installed sites were normal and everything (virtuals hosts/ sites) was working normally but suddenly it stopped listening to 80 and went on 7080 and 7081 any idea why this could happen. Sites are working on 7080.

If I change the port in ports.conf from 7080 to 80, sites stop working and I can see the generic webserver start page (which we can see usually before setting up any site)

Answer (score 0):

You must have

```
Listen 80
```

in httpd.conf , you may also have some troubles with virtuals, then the root changes, but with the info you post is hard to say, try to post the result of ps and netstat on ports 7080 and 7081 for further analysis.

Comment: I do have Listen 80, and I have tried to reconfigure using plesk command 
`/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all`
after port change but now it starts downloading the index.php file instead of displaying it

Answer (score 0):

1- used port other than 80 in apache, ports.conf and in per host confs in vhosts/domain.com/conf
2- turned on nginx on 80 
3- and it works.

plesk uses nginx as a proxy to serve webpage from apache which is running on some other port like 8080 and for ssl 8081 or 7081 and so on.

Just make sure nginx and apache are not tyring to use same ports it wont work.